# GPS radius search with Php 5 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `PlaceID | PlaceName | Lat | Lon` as my database structure.

Say I have my current latitude and longitude as

```
$lat = "37.331862";
$lon = "-122.029937";
```

I want to find places that are in a 100 feet radius. Might allow the user to choose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may be interested in checking out the following presentation:

- [Geo/Spatial Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)<sup>1</sup> by [Alexander Rubin](http://www.arubin.org/blog/presentations/)

The author describes how you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in MySQL to order by proximity and limit your searches to a defined range. He also describes how to avoid a full table scan for such queries, using traditional indexes on the latitude and longitude columns.

---

<sup>1</sup> [PDF Version](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf)